# How can I monitor deletion of /dev/null

Tags: inode, inotify

Usually I use inotfiy_add_watch to monitor deletion of files, it works for regular files or even most device files(/dev/zero,etc...), but fails for /dev/null. It seems that any operations to it will not trigger inotify events. Why？
Is there any other way to monitor rm /dev/null?
thx!

Comment: why would you do it? i mean after root/sudo can do that

Comment: cause I am working on a shared server that many modules or program with root permission are running on and recently /dev/null was deleted a couple of times. I am trying to find out who did this.

Comment: You should follow the principle of running programs with least required privileges.Your current setup seems way too fragile.

Comment: i am unsure if `chattr +i /dev/null` might work but you should remember that it may be a dangerous situation

Comment: Basically, this question has already some solutions like questions [266717] or [899956]

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, inotify is limited in that it is file system specific. [Documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) says that "various pseudo-filesystems such as /proc, /sys, and /dev/pts are not monitorable with inotify"

[Linux audit system](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-defining_audit_rules_and_controls) is capable of logging arbitrary system calls. An example file monitoring watch you might put in `/etc/audit/rules.d/specialdev.rules` could be:

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink,unlinkat,rename,renameat -F success=1 -F path=/dev/null -k specialdev
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink,unlinkat,rename,renameat -F success=1 -F path=/dev/null -k specialdev
```

Note the filtering to specific system calls that actually delete the file, not just write to it. Query recent entries with something like:

```
ausearch --start yesterday --end now  --key specialdev
```

You can tell from these log entries when it happened, the process ID and comm, various flavors of uid, and selinux context. Good clues, but you still have to do a bit of looking for the broken shell script or whatever.